# Ubuntu 21.04 Terminal not respopnding to keyboard

Tags: gnome-terminal, 21.04

First I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> And it opens the terminal but then I am not able to type.
I am using Ubuntu desktop on a raspberry pi 4b I can type anywhere else but not in the terminal.

Comment: Have you configured your Terminal to run a script or application when opening? If so, you may need to press [Ctrl]+[Z] (to suspend) or [Ctrl]+[C] (to cancel) to restore functionality 

Comment: No I just flashed it today and only updated every thing

Comment: Type `stty sane`, or `stty echo`. Read `man stty`. Or, if you have typed ^S, type ^Q.

Comment: @waltinator It is not responding to the keyboard.